# class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated while trying to compile with mysql++ library

Tags: c++, compilation, libmysql

I'm facing a compilation problem while trying to use mysql++.h in my C++ program on an ASUS Tinker Board.

Includes look like this :

```
#include <mysql++.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

G++ command executed is this one :

`g++ -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql++ -L/usr/lib -lmysqlpp -lmysqlclient mysql.c -o mysql`

Output contains the following :

```
In file included from /usr/include/mysql++/sql_buffer.h:31:0,
                 from /usr/include/mysql++/stadapter.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/mysql++/qparms.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/mysql++/query.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/mysql++/mysql++.h:58,
                 from mysql.c:1:
/usr/include/mysql++/refcounted.h: In constructor ‘mysqlpp::RefCountedPointer<T, Destroyer>::RefCountedPointer(T*)’:
/usr/include/mysql++/refcounted.h:104:8: warning: ‘template<class> class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   std::auto_ptr<T> exception_guard(counted_);
        ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:81:0,
                 from /usr/include/mysql++/refcounted.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/mysql++/sql_buffer.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/mysql++/stadapter.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/mysql++/qparms.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/mysql++/query.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/mysql++/mysql++.h:58,
                 from mysql.c:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:49:28: note: declared here
   template<typename> class auto_ptr;
                            ^~~~~~~~
```

I tried to modify file "/refcounted.h" by changing "std::auto_ptr" by "std::unique_ptr", it compiles successfully, but I get a "Segmentation fault" while trying to run my program.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a newer version of the library you could be using? Can you compile it with an older c++ standard?

Comment: You're either going to ignore the warning, fall back to an older standard, upgrade the library, or rewrite `mysql++.h` to use a `std::unique_ptr`/`std::shared_ptr`

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` (deprecated in modern C++) does not have quite the same semantics as `std::unique_ptr`.  Not a drop-in replacement, requires looking at the code.

Comment: Either mysql library is old or it is just your version of it. `auto_ptr` has been deprecated for a while.

Comment: Let mysql GPL crap go into oblivion and switch to mariadb's boost-licensed [C++ client](https://github.com/viaduck/mariadbpp) (note: mariadb is backward-compatible with mysql).